# parsing xml attribute: strange Encoding issue

Tags: html, r, parsing, encoding, web-scraping

I get a strange encoding problem when I try to parse a certain attribute of an xml/html document.
Here a reproducible example , containing 2 items with 2 titles (note the use of french accent here)

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('<note>
              <item title="é">1</item>
              <item title="ï">3</item>
          </note>',asText=TRUE,encoding='UTF-8')
```

Now using `xpathApply`  , I can read my items like this. Note that special accents are well formatted here.

```
xpathApply(doc,'//item')

[[1]]
<item title="é">1</item> 

[[2]]
<item title="ï">3</item>
```

But When I try to read my attribute title , I get this :

```
xpathApply(doc,'//item',xmlGetAttr,'title')
[[1]]
[1] "Ã©"

[[2]]
[1] "Ã¯"
```

I tried other xpath versions like :

```
  xpathApply(doc,'//item/@title') 
  xmlAttrs(xpathApply(doc,'//item')[[1]])
```

But this doesn't work. Any help please?

Comment: This works fine for me. R 3.0.0 i686-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: On windows this error is reproducible.

Comment: The strings “Ã©” and “Ã¯” are the UTF-8 encoded representations of “é” and “ï” when misinterpreted as ISO 8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not pretty and I cant test on this linux machine but try:

```
  xpathApply(doc,'//item',
         function(x) iconv(xmlAttrs(x,'title'), "UTF-8", "UTF-8"))
[[1]]
title 
  "é" 

[[2]]
title 
  "ï"
```

`xmlAttrs` calls `RS_XML_xmlNodeAttributes` examining this code there appears to be no facility for handling encoding. `xmlValue` calls `R_xmlNodeValue` this has encoding added. Looking at `?xmlValue` we have `encoding: experimental functionality and parameter related to encoding.` Maybe encoding on the attributes will be added at a later date.

Comment: from @Jukka K. Korpela comment it might help

Comment: thanks! I test it and it works. I just simplify your answer. No need to use `lapply` here.